# Is this a valid German Datetime Culture format?

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

So I'm using an API where a datetime is retrieved in the following format `DIE, 28. AUG 2018 12:38:38`

The closest datetime format I found was this `ddd, dd. MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss`.
 It works only if its `DI` , but the API provides this day as `DIE`.

Does a format exist that can parse `DIE, 28. AUG 2018 12:38:38` I believe that the developers of this API use some different format.

Does anyone know what it could be ?

EDIT: some code I tried

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string DateTimeFormat = "ddd, dd. MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    var deCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

    string input = "DIE, 28. AUG 2018 14:12:01";

    // both throws exception
    var timestamp1 = DateTime.ParseExact(input, DateTimeFormat, deCultureInfo);
    var timestamp2 = DateTime.Parse(input, deCultureInfo);


    //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(deCultureInfo));

}
```

Comment: It's interesting that `MON, 27. AUG 2018 12:38:38` works. Week days are usually abbreviated with only 2 letters in Germany. And the only 3 letter week day that works with `DateTime.Parse` is money with `Mon`.

Comment: actually it works if CultureInfo is ` CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` , so you are right its a misleading info. I edited it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to offer another option: *Just don't*.

Whatever that part is, it's redundant. There is no way the 28th of August 2018 will be anything else. The information there has no value to a computer. That format is meant for humans, who cannot just "look that up" in a few CPU cycles.

Don't parse `input`, just parse `input.Split(",").Last().Trim()`. This API obviously isn't written by experts or not meant to be used by another computer (German date format, week day, *wrong* format for weekday). It seems like this is a string that is displayed to end users of a product. Consider it a risk for breaking changes at any time, it's probably whatever user's "like best" at a specific time.

Answer (score 8):

You can override `ddd` in the property `AbbreviatedDayNames` of the used `DateTimeFormatInfo`:

```
const string DateTimeFormat = "ddd, dd. MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";
var deCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

var input = "DIE, 28. AUG 2018 14:12:01";

CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;

// addjust this to your german strings
dtfi.AbbreviatedDayNames = new[] { "SON", "MON", "DIE", "MIT", "DON", "FRE", "SAM" };

var timestamp1 = DateTime.ParseExact(input, DateTimeFormat, dtfi);
```

See this from the [doku.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-ddd-custom-format-specifier)